# Porting a Raku grep closure with functions and operators into C++

Tags: c++, c++17

Here is a sample Raku code which uses a *grep closure* with a sample criteria consisting of a function and logical operators:

```
print "$_, " for ( grep  { is-prime $_ and $_ > 5 and not ($_ == 11 or $_ == 13) }, 1..20);
# Output is: 7, 17, 19
```

I'd like to port this into `C++` using a `vector` or a `list` and a *lambda* in which I can set the sample criteria. Here's my take:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int num){
    bool flag=true;
    for(int i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
       if(num % i == 0) {
          flag = false;
          break; } }
    return flag;}
int main(){
  vector<int> a(20);
  iota(begin(a), end(a), 1); 
  vector<int> b(a.size());
  auto end = copy_if(cbegin(a), cend(a), begin(b),
             [](int x) { return isPrime(x) & ( x > 5 ) & !( (x == 11) | (x == 13) ); });
  b.erase(end, b.end()); 
  for (auto n: b) 
    cout << n << '\n';
  // Output is: 7, 17, 19
}
```

I'm trying yo make it without using `copy_if` i.e. by using `find_if` so that I don't have to create the auxiliary vector `b` Here is my take:

```
for (auto x : a) cout << find_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [x](){return isPrime(x) & ( x > 5 ) & !( (x == 11) | (x == 13));});
```

But it doesn't work. How to do it?

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question that’s difficult to answer concisely and is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. Instead of leaving us to speculate on what you might need, give us something to build so we can focus help in those areas where it’s most needed.

Comment: Can you show the program you've already written, and explain how exactly your program doesn't work or doesn't produce the expected results? You have to show your work first; it must meet all requirements for a [mre]; and it must be a good-faith real attempt to implement your program and not a few token lines of code, before asking for help on stackoverflow.com. *We don't write entire programs for other people*, here. For more information, see [ask] questions, take the [tour], and read the [help].

Comment: There are lots of problems with the last line of code you added.  Are you really just asking for help with that, independently of the Perl aspect?

Comment: @DavisHerring I've just edited the post. When I posted this post last night it was very late *3 AM* so it was in a horrible state. Now it's better. Ops! As per your question: I'm basically asking this to grasp the usage of `find_if` for this particular case, i.e. it's independent of Perl, really.

Comment: This appears to be Raku code (formerly known as Perl6). [Just saying 'Perl code' implies Perl5]. Also you need a comma after the closing curly of the grep block ;-).

Comment: @jubilatious1 I've corrected them. Sometimes ambigious expressions and typos come in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Perl calls `grep` here is called a **filter** in C++ (and some other contexts).  C++20 [offers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view) `std::ranges::filter_view` for the purpose, but since this question is tagged for C++17…

The `find_if` approach you tried doesn't make sense because it still involves iterating over every element (and asks the library to search with a "predicate" that takes no arguments).

It's certainly possible to use `std::find_if` to **advance** an iterator to each new value of interest in turn:

```
for(auto i=a.begin(),e=a.end();i!=e;
    i=find_if(i+1,e,[](int x)
      {return isPrime(x) & ( x > 5 ) && !( (x == 11) || (x == 13));})
  cout << n << '\n';
```

(Note the logical instead of bitwise operators.)  Since this involves an **explicit** loop (to keep track of the start position for each search) it's no better than the purely imperative approach of considering every element:

```
for(auto n : a)
  if(isPrime(x) && ( x > 5 ) && !( (x == 11) || (x == 13) ))
    cout << n << '\n';
```

Perhaps the most natural approach to avoiding the copy prior to C++20 is to use `std::copy_if` but with a **stream iterator** as the output "sequence":

```
copy_if(cbegin(a), cend(a), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"),
        [](int x) { return isPrime(x) && ( x > 5 ) && !( (x == 11) || (x == 13) ); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Prior to C++20, there isn't a `std` equivalent of `1..20` usable with `for ( : )`, you would instead use `for (;;)`.

```
auto criteria = [](int x){ return isPrime(x) && (x > 5) && (x != 11) && (x != 13); };

for (int x = 1; x <= 20; ++x) {
    if (criteria(x)) {
        std::cout << x;
    }
}
```